# failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/aflbs/www/www/scholarshipcontest/wp-settings.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I just changed hosting companies and I have created a new WP install and we created a new website (We did not move over the old site). I just realized there was a second WP install on the old hosting account for a scholarship contest and  I need to move that over to the new hosting company. I moved over the database and all of the files. I also updated the wp-config file with the database and username/password. But when I try to verify the site here aflbs.org/scholarshipcontest I am getting the below errors. Am I missing a step somewhere?

> Warning:
>   require(/home/aflbs/www/www/scholarshipcontest/wp-includes/load.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/aflbs/www/www/scholarshipcontest/wp-settings.php on line 19
>
> Warning:
>   require(/home/aflbs/www/www/scholarshipcontest/wp-includes/load.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/aflbs/www/www/scholarshipcontest/wp-settings.php on line 19
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/aflbs/www/www/scholarshipcontest/wp-includes/load.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/php56/lib/php') in
>   /home/aflbs/www/www/scholarshipcontest/wp-settings.php on line 19

Comment: You need to check `/home/aflbs/www/www` is the web root and if not rectify it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether web server have appropriate permission to access files or not. This usually happens due to permission or ownership.

Try changing permissions and see if it works.

Comment: I did check permissions and those are set up correctly. The domain name is aflbs.org, so I am assuming the web root of /home/aflbs/www/www is correct. Any other ideas? I also tried creating a subdomain and placing it there, but I am getting the same error message.